# Does yelp have any widgets or code that I can use to integrate yelp into my site?

Tags: asp-classic, embed, widget

I am trying to integrate yelp into a website I'm working on.  I'm really hoping to find a widget created by the yelp team, or another reputable source.  I'd like to be able to set it up to search for restaurants in a certain location, seattle, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yelp has a full API, but if you're hoping for a free widget then you are out of luck as I don't know of any.  But really, developing with the API is pretty simple.  They have good examples as well.

[Yelp API](http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation)

Answer (score 4):

I made a customizable yelp widget which allows you to optionally show recent positive reviews and style the widget for your specific site.  Check it out: http://chrisawren.com/widgets/yelp/

Answer (score -2):

If you see a Yelp! widget that you would like to have for your website, simply right click on the widget and select "inspect element" to see the HTML for the widget. If the HTML reference the yelp.com site then it's a FREE widget.

Just copy and paste the HTML code into any text editor and replace/substitute the name of the business and the Yelp! ID for the business with the one for the business for whom you are creating the widget.

To obtain the correct name and ID, simply go to Yelp.com, search for the business and viola ... they provide you with the name and ID.

It's definitely not rocket science.

Comment: This is not a professional approach to solving the problem.  In addition, I've recently checked the Yelp website, and there are still no Yelp widgets available.